# Make the Edit path the same as the show page in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In the profile page in my views I created an edit profile tab so the User can edit the profile in the show page. I am using a custom Devise controller but I am not sure how to tackle having the route for edit as the same as the show page.

This is my controller

```
 class Teachers::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
      # before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create],
      # before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  #GET /resource/sign_up
   def new
     super
   end

   def sign_up_params
        params.require(:teacher).permit(:name, :avatar, :email, :password)
   end

   #POST /resource/
   def create
    super
  end

  # GET /resource/edit
  def edit
     super
   end
```

and this is my routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :teachers, controllers: { registrations: 'teachers/registrations' }
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

root to: "teachers#index"
resources :teachers
resources :students
resources :courses
resources :behavior_reports
resources :participation_reports
resources :grades
resources :parents
resources :attendances

end
```

Comment: Please describe more about question . " I am not sure how to tackle having the route for edit as the same as the show page."